# Nth child selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Im having difficulty using the nth child selector. I have this html code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
   <ul class="mh-menu">
      <li>
         <a href="#">
            <span>Chairman of the Board</span>
            <span>Name</span>
         </a>
         <img src="images/richard.jpg" alt="richard"/>
         <p>Some Text</p>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="#">
            <span>Chief Executive Officer</span>
            <span>Name</span>
         </a>
         <img src="images/scott.jpg" alt="scott"/>
         <p>Some text</p>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="#">
            <span>Executive Vice President</span>
            <span>Name</span>
         </a>
         <img src="images/dana.png" alt="dana"/>
         <p>Some Text</p>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a href="#">
             <span>Executive Vice President</span>
             <span>Name</span>
          </a>
          <img src="images/jay.jpg" alt="jay"/>
          <p>Some text</p>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Along with this CSS:

**CSS**

```
.mh-menu li img {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 1;
   left: 0px;
   top: 0px;
   opacity: 0;
   -webkit-transition: left 0.4s ease-in-out, opacity 0.6s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: left 0.4s ease-in-out, opacity 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: left 0.4s ease-in-out, opacity 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: left 0.4s ease-in-out, opacity 0.6s ease-in-out;
    transition: left 0.4s ease-in-out, opacity 0.6s ease-in-out;    
    }

.mh-menu li p {
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 540px;
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: left 0.4s ease-in-out, opacity 0.6s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: left 0.4s ease-in-out, opacity 0.6s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: left 0.4s ease-in-out, opacity 0.6s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: left 0.4s ease-in-out, opacity 0.6s ease-in-out;
  transition: left 0.4s ease-in-out, opacity 0.6s ease-in-out;
  }

 .mh-menu li:hover img {
 left: 300px;
  opacity: 1;
  }

   .mh-menu li:hover p {
  left: 540px;
  opacity: 1;
 text-align: left;
 }
```

Basically it's a menu that when you hover over the name, the image along with some text pops out of the right side. Right now the images and text all pop out at the top, however I want to move the images down so that when you hover over the name, the image pops out of the top of the name span. How can I used nth-child to select each image to move it down with the top: CSS attribute?

**jsFiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/FGGpY/5/

Comment: please prepare a Fiddle

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean... something like just removing the `top: 0px;`?

Comment: Test your code here http://jsfiddle.net/ and post the result so we can understand better with live working code

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FGGpY/5/

*updated with jsFiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.mh-menu li img {
    /* top: 0px; */
    margin-top:-90px;
}
```

Remove the `top: 0px` from `.mh-menu li img` and maybe add `margin-top` negative whatever the `height` of the `li` item. Not really a `nth selector` issue

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/feitla/FGGpY/6/)

Answer (score 0):

It's a little tricky to determine the big picture or exactly what you want it to look like.  But I bet something like this might get you started:

```
.mh-menu li:hover:nth-child(2) img {
    top: 70px;
}
```

OR...just remove the "top" declaration from the rule you have with this (?):

```
.mh-menu li img {...}
```